# can't make flash working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I am developing an application  with nodeJs, Express 3.4.1 and passport 0.1.17, everything is ok, except I can not make req.flash working, I read many posts, they advised me that since Express 3 the support for flash has been removed and should use connect-flash,paying attention   where it is used in my server, but nothing is working, here the important part of my server.js:

```
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs');
var passport = require('passport');
var neo = require('neo4j');
var db = new neo.GraphDatabase('http://localhost:7474');
var neoDb = new neo.GraphDatabase('http://localhost:7474');
var app = express();


// Bootstrap models
var modelsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib/models');
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
});

// Populate empty DB with dummy data
//require('./lib/db/dummydata');

// Controllers
var api = require('./lib/controllers/api');
// Express Configuration
app.configure(function(){
app.use('/media', express.static(__dirname + '/media'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
//app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
//for authentication
app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'blabla' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    });
```

I am thinking to switch to angular, but am unsure if it makes sense to switch from ejs to angular,  what is best approach  to flash message to the user?

Comment: When you say "nothing is working", what is happening? What errors or debugging results have you produced?  How are you using `req.flash`?  And when you say 'best approach to flash message to the user', do you understand what `connect-flash` does and that it is not directly related to ejs, angular or any other client-side issue?

Comment: I do not exactly what re.flash does it,never used before I imagine it should give some message to the user, I followed an example from internet,  req.flash is used inside a passport strategy: return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));  obviously is not directly related with ejs and angular , but I do not know how to recover the message from the flash using ejs.

Comment: `connect-flash` attaches a `flash` property onto the `req` object. `ejs` on node lets you render a template for the client, passing in objects for ejs to use as it converts the template to a final page.  To use `req.flash` you need to pass your `ejs` template the `req.flash` data.  The problem here is not with the technology but your understanding of it. Having been there myself, let me suggest you spend time on express.js and ejs fundamentals so you grasp how these work together as a unit. it will make middleware and passport easier, later.